# Why is my array.forEach() not breaking the iteration and returning 'true'?

Tags: javascript, foreach, boolean-logic

I am trying to write a function that compares the values in an array to see if they match a constant "flightValue".  However, even when it returns a 'true' value, the loop doesn't stop and ultimately returns an undefined value.

What is the break in my logic here?

```
// Write a function that takes an integer flightLength (in minutes) and an array of integers movieLengths (in minutes) and returns a boolean indicating whether there are two numbers in movieLengths whose sum equals flightLength.

let moviesArray = [75, 120, 65, 140, 80, 95, 45, 72];

function canWatchTwoMovies(flightLength, array) {
  let startIndex = 0;
  let endIndex = array.length;

  array.forEach((el, index)=> {
    let currentPointer = index;
    for(i = currentPointer+1; i < endIndex; i++) {
      if(array[currentPointer] + array[i] == flightLength) {
        // Uncomment the console.log to see that there is a 'true' value
        // console.log(array[currentPointer] + array[i] == flightLength);
        // Why is this not breaking the loop and returning "true"?
        return true;
      }
    }
  });
  // I have commented out the default return value
  // return false;
  console.log("The function doesn't break and always runs to this point");
}

// Should return 'true' for addition of first two elements '75' and '120'
canWatchTwoMovies(195, moviesArray);
```

Edit:
Here is the cleaned up code per Maor Refaeli's reply below:

```
function canWatchTwoMovies(flightLength, array) {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    let currentPointer = index;
    for(let i = currentPointer+1; i < array.length; i++) {
      if(array[currentPointer] + array[i] == flightLength) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: That's not how `.forEach()` works. It always iterates through the entire array. It does not pay attention to values returned from the callback function.

Comment: because forEach does not exit.... And forEach from not return anything... Maybe you want some()

Comment: You want to look into `.some()` instead. Also `i` should be declared with `var` or `let`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `forEach` you declare a function that will be executed for every single item in the array.
One way to achieve what you want is using a for-loop:

```
// Write a function that takes an integer flightLength (in minutes) and an array of integers movieLengths (in minutes) and returns a boolean indicating whether there are two numbers in movieLengths whose sum equals flightLength.

let moviesArray = [75, 120, 65, 140, 80, 95, 45, 72];

function canWatchTwoMovies(flightLength, array) {
  let startIndex = 0;
  let endIndex = array.length;

  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; i++) {
    let el = array[index];
    let currentPointer = index;
    for(i = currentPointer+1; i < endIndex; i++) {
      if(array[currentPointer] + array[i] == flightLength) {
        // Uncomment the console.log to see that there is a 'true' value
        // console.log(array[currentPointer] + array[i] == flightLength);
        // Why is this not breaking the loop and returning "true"?
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  // I have commented out the default return value
  // return false;
  console.log("The function doesn't break and always runs to this point");
}

// Should return 'true' for addition of first two elements '75' and '120'
canWatchTwoMovies(195, moviesArray);
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the solution.  I cleaned up the code a bit here: